# tomcat server port and tomcat connector port are these same?

Tags: centos, tomcat

Is the Tomcat server port and the Tomcat connector port the same or should they be same?

I changed my [Tomcat5](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-55.cgi) server port to 8005. my centOS server shows that the Tomcat service is running. Howver, I am unable to access it through the browser.

Should I also change the connector port? I have ISPconfig installed on centOS.

Connector port config looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       address="0.0.0.0"
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These values should not be the same, and likely are causing one of the Connectors to fail to start.  The reason you cannot connect via a browser is that the service listening on 8005 is not HTTP, but rather the default Tomcat listener for issuing management commands (like shutdown).

You will need to define an HTTP connector in order to connect directly from a web browser.  This would look something like:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Comment: i have same as you said.. defining HTTP connector. but still i am unable to connect. my ISPConfig is running on port 8080

Comment: If your ISPConfig panel is running on port 8080, then Tomcat cannot listen to HTTP on port 8080 as well.  Use a different port for either ISPConfig or Tomcat and restart the service.

Comment: yes my ispconfig is running at 8080. and i configured tomcat to 8005 "<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">"

Comment: There is a difference between the Server port and the HTTP listener.  You need to set the Server port and HTTP listener to two **different**, **unused** ports.

Comment: i have different ports for server and connector, and these are unused ports. but still i am unable to access.

Comment: The connector config you added shows that the HTTP connector is using port 8080, but you also said ISPConfig is using port 8080.  When you go to http://servername:8080/ you see your ISPConfig UI right?